# How to center child div dynamically using class?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

How to center child div dynamically by using class "center". I can't find any reference, and don't know what should I search.

Someone knows how to do it either in *css* or *tailwind* way?

---

Here are the example output in image below. (in snippet below color black was centered)

[image]

```css
.parent {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
}

.orange { background: orange; }
.yellow { background: yellow; }
.black { background: black; }
.green { background: green; }
.gray { background: gray; }
.violet { background: violet; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child orange"></div>
  <div class="child yellow"></div>
  <div class="child black"></div>
  <div class="child green center"></div>
  <div class="child gray"></div>
  <div class="child violet"></div>
</div>
```

---

Here is my also [codepen](https://codepen.io/escbooster12/pen/BaZVGEg)

Comment: You can use `order` from `flexbox` to achieve this. But you need to provide the order value also dynamically. And should be given to all elements.

Comment: Is the number of children going to change? Or will it always be five? (or six?)

Comment: If you have fixed number of lines, you can try `CSS grid` with `grid-template-areas`. Once you give some child element style `grid-area` and point it to the central area, it will appear in the center https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas

Comment: @dave there are 6 child (fixed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a way to center the divs dynamically using CSS frameworks.
But here is my Javascript solution to this problem:

`Note:` I have removed the height from parent div as the height is fixed in the child divs.

1. First we need to select the parent element

```js
let parent = document.querySelector("#parent");
```

2. Calculate total number of child

```js
let totalChild = parent.childElementCount;
```

3. Find middle position

```js
const middle = Math.floor(totalChild / 2);
```

4. Select the div with class center

```js
let centerDiv = document.querySelector("#parent .center");
```

5. Delete the center div

```js
parent.removeChild(centerDiv);
```

6. Insert the center div to the middle position of parent

```js
parent.insertBefore(centerDiv, parent.children[middle]);
```

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      #parent {
        width: 300px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }

      .child {
        height: 100px;
      }

      .orange {background: orange;}
      .yellow {background: yellow;}
      .black {background: black;}
      .green {background: green;}
      .gray {background: gray;}
      .violet {background: violet;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parent">
      <div class="child orange"></div>
      <div class="child yellow"></div>
      <div class="child black"></div>
      <div class="child green"></div>
      <div class="child gray"></div>
      <div class="child violet center"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
      // STEP 1: select parent div
      let parent = document.querySelector("#parent");

      // STEP 2: calculate total number of child
      let totalChild = parent.childElementCount;

      // STEP 3: find middle position
      const middle = Math.floor(totalChild / 2);

      // STEP 4: Select the div with class center
      let centerDiv = document.querySelector("#parent .center");

      // STEP 5: Delete the center div
      parent.removeChild(centerDiv);

      // STEP 6: Insert the center div to the middle position of parent
      parent.insertBefore(centerDiv, parent.children[middle]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If there are 5 (odd) elements in the parent div:
Index 2 will be the middle element

If there are 6 (even) elements in the parent div:
Index 3 will be the middle element

If you want index 2 when there are 6 (even) elements, you can subtract 1 from totalCount in step 2.

```js
let totalChild = parent.childElementCount - 1;
```

`UPDATE:`
Since you wanted to display the div centered based on the height of the parent div, you can try this:

In this code, middle position is calculated by dividing Parent div height by child div height.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      #parent {
        height: 500px;
        width: 300px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }

      .child {
        height: 100px;
      }

      .orange {background: orange;}
      .yellow {background: yellow;}
      .black {background: black;}
      .green {background: green;}
      .gray {background: gray;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parent">
      <div class="child orange center"></div>
      <div class="child yellow"></div>
      <div class="child black"></div>
      <div class="child green"></div>
      <div class="child gray"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
      // STEP 1: select parent and child div
      let parent = document.querySelector("#parent");
      let child = document.querySelector(".child");

      // STEP 2: calculate height of parent and child div
      let parentHeight = parent.clientHeight;
      let childHeight = child.clientHeight;

      // STEP 3: Total number of blocks that needs to be there
      const totalBlocks = Math.floor(parentHeight / childHeight);

      // STEP 4: Find the middle block
      const middle = Math.floor(totalBlocks / 2);

      // STEP 5: Select the div with class center
      let centerDiv = document.querySelector("#parent .center");

      // STEP 6: Delete the center div
      parent.removeChild(centerDiv);

      // STEP 7: Insert the center div to the middle position of parents height
      parent.insertBefore(centerDiv, parent.children[middle]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`UPDATE:` Looking at the images you have posted, what you can do is find the difference between the div that needs to be centered and the position of the middle block of the parent like this:

[image]

After finding the difference, you can offset all the child divs.
To select all the child elements, I have used a container div as a wrapper for all the child divs.

- Added `position: relative;` to parent id so that child can calculate the offset value relative to the parent.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      #parent {
        height: 500px;
        width: 300px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        position: relative;
      }

      .child {
        height: 100px;
      }

      .orange {background: orange;}
      .yellow {background: yellow;}
      .black {background: black;}
      .green {background: green;}
      .gray {background: gray;}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parent">
      <div id="container">
        <div class="child orange"></div>
        <div class="child yellow"></div>
        <div class="child black"></div>
        <div class="child green center"></div>
        <div class="child gray"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      // Select parent, child container and child div
      let parent = document.querySelector("#parent");
      let child = document.querySelector(".child");
      let childContainer = document.querySelector("#container");

      // STEP 1: find the middle position of block in the parent div
      let parentHeight = parent.clientHeight;
      let childHeight = child.clientHeight;

      let totalBlocks = Math.floor(parentHeight / childHeight); // 5
      let middleBlock = Math.floor(totalBlocks / 2); // 2
      let middlePosition = middleBlock * childHeight; // 200px

      // STEP 2: Find the position of div that needs to be in the center.
      let centerDivPosition = document.querySelector(".center").offsetTop; // 300px

      // Step 3: find the difference between them
      let offestValue = middlePosition - centerDivPosition; // -100

      // Step 4: offset the container position
      childContainer.style.position = "relative";
      childContainer.style.top = `${offestValue}px`;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think it doing re-insertion. I wanted to move it upwards (see my updated image in the description).

Comment: @schutte Ohh okay, got it. Let's say there is only one element in parent div. In that case, where does the centered div need to go? Remain at the bottom or at the middle?

Comment: if it has class `center` it will move center. if not at the top. But my scenario is, there is 6 child divs (not dynamic)

Comment: @schutte Okay, I have updated the code. You can change the height of parent and child now, also add or remove the child elements. See if it works for you.

Comment: i tried to put class `center` at green-child div, but it does not look like at the above image. (see "CENTER GREEN" at the description image) :)

Comment: @schutte then you can find the difference between the div that needs to be centered and the position of the middle block of the parent. After that move all the child divs position. See if that works. Updated the answer.

Comment: It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this simply by using NativeJS/jQuery. Check the below snippet.

Let me in case you require further assistance in solving this.

You need to programmatically provide `order` values to the `childs`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var items = $('.parent .child');
  var otherItems = $('.parent .child:not(.center)');
  var centerOrder = parseInt(items.length/2) + 1;
  $('.center').css('order', centerOrder);
  otherItems.each(function(index, item) {
    if(index < otherItems.length/2)
      $(item).css('order', centerOrder - 1);
    else 
      $(item).css('order', centerOrder + 1);
  })
})
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
}

.orange { background: orange; }
.yellow { background: yellow; }
.black { background: black; }
.green { background: green; }
.gray { background: gray; }
.violet { background: violet; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child orange"></div>
  <div class="child yellow"></div>
  <div class="child green"></div>
  <div class="child gray"></div>
  <div class="child violet center"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think it doing re-insertion. I want it to move it upwards (see my updated image in the description).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned `tailwindcss`. You can use tailwind's order https://tailwindcss.com/docs/order to change order of the child divs.

In these example below you can send child-green to first. And also wrap it with `flex flex-col`.

```css
.parent {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
}

.orange { background: orange; }
.yellow { background: yellow; }
.black { background: black; }
.green { background: green; }
.gray { background: gray; }
.violet { background: violet; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.15/tailwind.min.css">

<div class="parent">
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <div class="child orange"></div>
    <div class="child yellow"></div>
    <div class="child black"></div>
    <div class="child green order-first"></div>
    <div class="child gray"></div>
    <div class="child violet"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but how to center. I want to hide also if overlaps. see my updated picture in the description.